# $f(x) = 3x+5$ write $f(x+3)$ as a function of $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So you substitute to get
$$f(x+3)= 3(x+3)+5 =3x+9+5= 3x+14 $$

Then you make x the subject for the other equation
$$x= (f(x)-5)/3$$

Then you sub in the $x$ for the other equation.

I don't understand the logic of making $x$ the subject to substitute. And why we substitute the $x$.
What are we doing algebraically.
I have looked at similar questions but they just work out the anwer and don't express it.

Why do we do this bit:
[So we substitute $x= (f(x)-5)/3$ into $3x+14$.
Which gives $3((f(x)-5)/3)+14
= (3f(x)-15/3)+14]$

Comment: Not following.  Since you have correctly remarked that $f(x+3)=3x+14=3x+5+9$ We instantly get $f(x+3)=f(x)+9$....wasn't that the goal?  I'm not sure what the rest of your argument concerns.

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look at the bottom part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay...

"Why do we do this bit: [So we substitute $x= \frac{(f(x)-5)}3$ into $3x+14$. Which gives $3(\frac{(f(x)-5)}3)+14..$]"

Okay if you have an expression in terms of $\color{orange}y$ so as $a\color{orange}{y} + b$  and you want to express it in terms of something else,  say $\color{blue}x$. and we know what $\color{orange}y$ is in terms of $\color{blue}x$, say $\color{blue}y=\color{green}{w\color{blue}x + z}$, we can substitute the other value of $\color{orange}y = \color{green}{w\color{blue}x + z}$ into the express to get:

$EXPRESSION = a\color{orange}y + b =$

$a[\text{anything else that is the same thing as }\color{orange}y ] + b=$

$a[ (\color{green}{w\color{blue}x + z}) \text{is the same thing as }\color{orange}y]+b =$

$a[\color{green}{w\color{blue}x + z}] + b=$

$a(\color{green}{w\color{blue}x + z}) + b$

And that is how substitution works.

In your problem we have $f(x) = 3x + 5$ and so

$f(x+3) = 3x + 14$.  But we want to express that in terms of $f(x)$.  So we need to replace the $x$ with "$\text{something that equals }x\text{ but is about }f(x)$".

So $f(x+3) = 3x + 14=$

$3[ x ] + 14=$

$3[\text{something that equals }x\text{ but is about }f(x)]+ 14$

So what can we put in that box that is equal to $x$ but is about $f(x)$.

Well.... as

$f(x) = 3x + 5$ if we express this in terms of $x$ we get

$f(x) = 3x + 5$

$f(x) - 5 = 3x$

$x = \frac {f(x) -5}3$.

So we just toss $\frac {f(x) -5}3$ into that box.

$f(x+3) = 3x + 14=$

$3[ x ] + 14=$

$3[\text{something that equals }x\text{ but is about }f(x)]+ 14=$

$3[\frac {f(x) -5}3 \text{ is equal to }x] +14=$

$3(\frac {f(x) -5}3) + 14=$

$\require{cancel}$
$\cancel 3(\frac {f(x) -5}{\cancel 3}) + 14=$

$(f(x) -5) + 14=$

$f(x) +9$.

So $f(x+3) = f(x) + 9$.

But you know we probably could have done this a lot quicker:

$f(x+3) = 3(x+3) + 5=$

$3x + 9 + 5 = $

$3x + 14 =$

$(3x + 5) + 9 =$

$f(x) + 9$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(3 + x) = 3x + 14 = (3x+5) + 9 = f(x) + 9.$

So, the question can be answered without the complexity of attempting to analyze $~x = \dfrac{f(x) - 5}{3}.$

Comment: start should be $f(3+x)$

Comment: @RobinSparrow Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=3x+5$, where $x=\frac{f(x)−5}{3}$. If you substitute in into $f(x+3)=3x+14$ we get: $$f(x+3)=3\frac{f(x)-5}{3}+14=f(x)+9$$
Thus $$f(x+3)=f(x)+9$$

It can be done this way or it can be done in a simplier way, which is noticing $$3x+5+9=f(x)+9=f(x+3)$$

Comment: What does it mean to substitute the x  into that equation why are we doing that?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If $something = anotherwayofsayingit$ and you have an $expression\ about \ something$ and you want to be an expression about $anotherwayofsayingit$ you can substitute $something$ with $anotherwayofsayingit$.  So for example if you have $2y+ 7$ and $y=5x + 3$ and you want to express $2y+7$ in terms of $x$ we can simply substitue $2y+7=2[someotherwayofsaying\ y] + 7 = 2[5x + 3] +7 = 10x +13$.  This is the same you have $f(x+3)=3x +14$ and we have $x=\frac{f(x)-5}3$ so we do $f(x+3)=3[x]+14=3[anythingelsethatequals\ x] +14=3[\frac{f(x)-5}3]+14$.

Comment: thank you it makes some sence

Comment: Hello in reply to your problem, you have to simplify, simple. If you don't simplify your making a problem for yourself, so what is the problem!

Comment: And I am also saying that you don't have to substitute x instead you can work it out in the simpler way which is listed down. Math is about ideas, simply substituting x is another idea that leads to the same answer, you don't have to, but doing it gives you a better intuitive idea

Comment: @MarxCarton I definitely agree (so much so I first found the "bottom part" unfathomable at first).  But 1) if this had been a complicated problem that wasn't so obvious the OP should have an algorithm/strategy to do this and 2) The OP had been told *exactly* how to do this by the abstract algorithm but didn't understand it even though it is a basic concept (although a tedious application) so as it *is* simple I feel it is necessary to explain the simple concept for the OP.

Comment: @fleablood I agree to you too, even difficult fuctions problems involve simple substitution, example if you have x^3+1/(x^3)=3, you can easily work out this problem with simple substitution and calculations, with binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can take multiple views on the situation.

One is purely algebraic, put a new variable in for $x$, in this case $x+3$, do a bit of legwork, and try to re-express the result as some modification of $f(x)$. In this case, $f(x+3)=3(x+3)+5=3x+14=f(x)+9$.

Another view is more geometric. $f(x+3)$ is by definition the plot of $f(x)$ shifted $3$ to the left. So the question becomes, what would we have to do to $f(x)$ to make it equivalent to being shifted $3$ to the left.

In the case of a linear $y=mx+b$ equation, all horizontal shifts $y=m(x-a)+b$ can also be written as $y=mx-ma+b$, which is clearly $y=mx+b-ma$, so $ma$ is a vertical offset that is equivalent to the horizontal shift $f(x-a)$.

In general, solving for $f(x+a)=F(f(x))$ can be though of as "what would make the original function look like the original function shifted to the side by some amount", at least in the kinds of situations you're probably working with.

Edit:

Since you are trying to straighten out the logic of substitution, and I don't think this has been directly stated so far, when you're in this situation with an $f(x)$, and you have solved it for $x$, such as $x=\frac{f(x)-5}{3}$, you have two options to substitute for x.

1. Evaluate $f(x+3)$, giving $3x+14$, then perform your substitution and simplify.
2. Substitute immediately so that you evaluate $f(\frac{f(x)-5}{3}+3)$, and then simplify.

Both of these approaches will work, and the simplification may be easier one way vs another depending on the nature of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the last approach in the end please could you explain number 2? Thanks.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is $3x+5$, use what is in the parentheses as $x$, and then simplify.